# How to find the more selection button in more selection window sap?

Tags: abap, sap-selection-screens

in my report I have a selection option

```
SELECT-OPTIONS: s_var for myvar.
```

If i click the button 'more selection' I got a popup with standard SAP option. BUT I dont find the button 'multiple selection' inside this window. Is there a way how to activate the button?

thanks[image: Multiple Selection]

Comment: Your question is kind of unclear.  1) How is myvar defined? 2) do you mean the "Multiple Selection for S_VAR" window with "Select Single Values", "Select Ranges", "Exclude Single Values", "Exclude Ranges" or do you mean some other window?

Comment: I add some screenshot, which you can see the multiple selection button. in my code i can't see it. any ideas?

Comment: I see it in my system.  How is myvar defined in your code?

Comment: Yes, I can see it also in my system. My question was I have implemented some selection s_var for myvar. And I declared myVar like myVar type /my_data_e/ which have at the end the type char. If I click the more selection button I can't see the multiple selection button in it.

Comment: I think i figured out what the problem is but using descriptions like myVar and my_data_e really don't help.  This problem is context dependent.  You should specify exactly what the data element is, and if it's custom, how the data element is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a search help.

```
data: myvar type ybctest-werks.

SELECT-OPTIONS: s_var for myvar MATCHCODE OBJECT H_T001W_C.
```

That should fix your problem.

This "just works" for standard fields like:

```
data: myvar type t001w-werks.

SELECT-OPTIONS: s_var for myvar
```

because that field has an explicit search help defined in the data dictionary (SE11->T001W->entry help/check tab).